# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 Upgrade Display Issue

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, display, amd-graphics

Upgraded desktop running AMD A10-7870K and Gigabyte F2A88XM-D3H Motherboard.  From Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04. Upon restart the monitor shows bios but then goes blank. No Ubuntu logon page. Rebooted pc from reset button. Same thing happened. Rebooted again and held shift button. No change. Noticed hard drive light active. Tried blindly logging on. Hard drive light was active for some time. Can ping desktop from a laptop. Could this desktop have a display issue with upgrade? Any ideas.

Update: Restarted pc and can hear Ubuntu startup sound.

Update: Plugged pc into HDMI and get picture with logon. Logged on and have desktop. VGA not working afer update?

VGA Out works only with HDMI attached

Here is a partial boot log. The errors and Radeon info that I saw.

```
[    3.254386] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    3.254389] [drm] Connector 0:
[    3.254390] [drm]   DVI-D-1
[    3.254392] [drm]   HPD3
[    3.254393] [drm]   DDC: 0x6550 0x6550 0x6554 0x6554 0x6558 0x6558 0x655c 0x655c
[    3.254394] [drm]   Encoders:
[    3.254396] [drm]     DFP2: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[    3.254397] [drm] Connector 1:
[    3.254397] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[    3.254398] [drm]   HPD1
[    3.254400] [drm]   DDC: 0x6530 0x6530 0x6534 0x6534 0x6538 0x6538 0x653c 0x653c
[    3.254400] [drm]   Encoders:
[    3.254401] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    3.254402] [drm] Connector 2:
[    3.254403] [drm]   VGA-1
[    3.254404] [drm]   HPD2
[    3.254405] [drm]   DDC: 0x6540 0x6540 0x6544 0x6544 0x6548 0x6548 0x654c 0x654c
[    3.254406] [drm]   Encoders:
[    3.254407] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY3
[    3.254408] [drm]     CRT1: NUTMEG
[    3.489293] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0728000
[    3.489296] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[    3.489298] [drm] size 8294400
[    3.489299] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    3.489300] [drm]    pitch is 7680
[    3.489675] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.489759] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x64
[    3.489786] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.516759] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.ALIB] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[    3.516767] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.VGA.ATC0] (Node ffff88042f0c41e0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    3.516775] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.VGA.ATCS] (Node ffff88042f0c41b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    3.523294] kfd kfd: Allocated 3944480 bytes on gart for device(1002:130f)
[    3.523312] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[    3.523315] kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device (1002:130f)
[    3.523338] Creating topology SYSFS entries
[    3.523421] kfd kfd: device (1002:130f) NOT added due to errors
[    3.523425] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0

[    5.231796] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[    5.231862] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD APU or Gigabyte Motherboard. Dont upgrade to 16.04lts. My VGA port only works with HDMI port connected to another monitor. Ended up Reloading with 14.04lts. All is well. Figure something is wrong with graphics driver. My Old laptop, an Intel based system works fine. Maybe the Radeon Driver? Just MY personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Turn of nomodeset when booting from grub.

See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166037

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.